# Android app how to test Development vs Live version

Tags: android, testing

We will be `Beta Testing` our app soon and was wondering how you guys test your Android app `development versions` before pushing to the `live version`?

Would like to have strictly an app version for development and one live version.

Would you suggest to just copy the entire project and rename the package name? This seems like a hacky way to do it as I would have to copy the altered code back to the live version when ready?

The purpose I ask is would like to be able to have other team members test the development versions too before we decide to push to live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's different aspects to your question.

If you're still using Eclipse ... some of this doesn't apply.

If you're using Android Studio:

**First aspect:** You can have as many build variants as you want; you can have different files / classes for any of them. Check out the [gradle documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants). Notice the difference between 'build types' and 'product flavors'. 
In my team we do not only have a release and a debug build variant, they too use a dev and production type of the backend API.

You could use a global variable like

```
isDebug = false / true
```

in a Settings class of which you have different version.

**Second aspect** is testing. We use [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) to distribute debug versions of the app to our internal testers. You can combine this with a CI tool like [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/).

**Third aspect:** is the deployment to the Google Play Store. There's several well documented and foolproof methods to get you alpha/beta app to your users. 
Also you can use staged rollouts to see if your new release works fine. Documentation can be [found here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en).

**Fourth aspect:** Version control. Doesn't matter if you use SVN or Git or whatever. You want to have different branches. We use one 'main' (default) branch only for versions that are tested and considered 'okay to release to the public', one 'development' branch that is considered the 'current stable state of development' and off that development branch people branch off their feature branches that they bring back in when their feature is tested and okay.

This can all be a bit confusing at start (especially bringing those aspects together) but will be quite clear to you as you use it. That's the crucial point: use those mechanisms. Don't do it the 'old school' way of building 'the one' release version, release it and *hope* everything goes well, but rather put out debug / beta versions all the time.

Hope this helps you, feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! This is very helpful. I am using Android Studio so this is great! We are using `DeployGate` for our distribution currently as it doesn't require users to sign up for anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload your release version app to Google Play not for production but for beta testing. Then you gonna need to register some teammates who will be able to DL and install it. These teammates have to have gmail acc (you gonna join them to one G+ group).
Another solution is to use Crashlytics since it has a special feature for betatesting. You will have to upload your bild to CL and testers will be able to intall it using CL. This way it doesn't matter which version you want to test - debug or release.